# Message in setup if XP SP3 is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I have a working setup project in VS2012 for a C#/WPF application including the setup for .NET Framework 4.0 if missing. On a Windows XP machine I found that this setup fails, if SP3 is not installed.

I understand that it fails, because SP3 is missing, but what I don't like is that the setup just says "failed". So I want a solution that tells the user that SP3 is required.

Here my questions:

1. Is it possible to set something like a target requirement in my setup, so the setup will tell the user that SP3 is required?
2. Or if 1. is not possible, can I also include XP SP3 in my setup? (caution, setup should also work on Vista and Win7)?
3. Or do you know another solution using VS2010 setup project?

I can't seem to find any possibility to set the required windows operating systems in my VS2010 setup project.

Comment: Check out this question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/4204194/250725.  The short answer is XP SP2 or below does not support the.NET4 framework, which is why it is failing when you try to install an app targetting .NET4.  Not sure how to check that in your installer though, but I believe you check to see if the appropriate .NET framework is installed

Comment: I don't want to install my application on Windows XP SP2. And my setup automatically detects that .NET 4.0 is missing. What I want is a message for the user saying something like "Sorry, but you need to install SP3 first". At the moment installation just fails with a message that doesn't help my users in any way.

Comment: I think it is possible (as I was told that by a colleague), but I've never done it.... have you seen this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda(VS.100).aspx

Comment: This would sure be a solution, but I think I have found a better one. I added a "Launch Condition" with "(VersionNT=501 and ServicePackLevel>=3) or WindowsBuild >= 6001". At the moment I unfortunatly can't test that, because the machine has now SP3 on it, but I'm pretty sure it will work. I will check if I set up another machine.