# Which entity framework should I use in visual studio 2012 with target framework is 3.5

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5

As the title. I'm currently working on a project in `visual studio 2012`. But in order to let user with `window xp` operating system can use it, I must set the target framework to 3.5. So which `entity framework` should I use?

Comment: But entity 4.0 use .net framework 4.0. I need to use .net framework 3.5 in my case

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4204289/1347784

Comment: Ever consider a client/server solution ?

Comment: @philsoady soady We don't have much option here since this software is a outsourcing project. Do you have any idea how can I use `entity framework 1` in `visual studio 2012`?

Comment: can you use .net 4.0 ? i am currently using .net framework 4.0 on my win xp machine with VS 2010 and EF 4.1

Comment: Just asked my customer, and they said that their company currently using a lot of xp sp2 machine, so they want to keep it at 3.5

Comment: The idea was the code you write that is deployed on these ancient machines calls a server program on a new machine. IE presentation only on the client.

Comment: Perhaps there is another ORM better suited to an older .net environment.  Id event consider not using an ORM given the old .net platform