# VB program does not run on older XP machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, cross-platform

First off, I do most my programming as tools for myself and know just enough to get by. I wrote a VB program which uses a vender's API DLL to communicate with a serial port device. I used VS Express. Works great on my Win 7 32-bit machine.

I handed my program off to a co-worker (didn't expect to share my tools) who has a XP 32-bit machine. I get a windows error that it "*is not a valid win32 application*" I made sure to include the vender's DLL with my executable.

I really don't want to have to install VS Express on his computer as that is how I have solved the issue in the past. I could use some pointers on cross-platform compatibility. Not looking to make my software universal, just to get it running on a XP machine.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you check the .Net Framework version your application is built against? [There's already a question discussing the supported versions on XP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4204194/205233).

Comment: Go smack your IT department for having an unsupported OS out in the field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xp only supports up to .NET framework 2.0 if you want to use it on all versions of xp.
So you need to check with version he has or you want to support.
So if you want it to run on Xp "All versions" you need to make it .NET framework 2.0

[Is .NET 4.0 Compatible with Windows XP SP2 or below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204194/is-net-4-0-compatible-with-windows-xp-sp2-or-below)

Comment: XP supported up to .Net 4.0. Of course, now XP is not supported at all.